# Create a new column in dataframe with values based on other column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in r :

```
         word     positive.polarity    negative.polarity 
1 interesting                 1                 0                         
2      boring                 0                 1
```

I try to add a new column called positive.ponderate.polarity which contains the value of positive.polarity * 3 if the context od words contains a special character , and positive.polarity /3 if not.

Any idea please to do this?

Thank you

Comment: You can use `ifelse`.   BTW, what is the special character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing what your "special character" is... I'm going to use the condition of : `"[o]{2}|[y]$"` or in basic terms

> if the word contains two "o's" OR ends in a 'y':  multiply by 3; if not divide by 3.

Using the `tm` package for the `stopwords` and `package::dplyr`

```
  # Created some data to mimic yours
  var_df <- data.frame(word = tm::stopwords(),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% mutate(
    positive.polarity = sample(0:1, nrow(.), TRUE)) %>% mutate(
    negative.polarity = ifelse(positive.polarity == 1, 0, 1)
  ) %>% 
   # Applying the condition and evaluating the variable formula if met
  mutate(
    positive.ponderate.polarity = ifelse(
        grepl("[o]{2}|[y]$", word), 
        positive.polarity * 3, 
        positive.polarity / 3)
    )

tail(var_df, 10)

    word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
165   no                 0                 1                   0.0000000
166  nor                 0                 1                   0.0000000
167  not                 1                 0                   0.3333333
168 only                 1                 0                   3.0000000
169  own                 1                 0                   0.3333333
170 same                 1                 0                   0.3333333
171   so                 0                 1                   0.0000000
172 than                 1                 0                   0.3333333
173  too                 1                 0                   3.0000000
174 very                 1                 0                   3.0000000
```